# Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory and ignoring directories with no reading permission

Tags: python, android, kivy, android-permissions, permission-denied

I need a program that lists all my directories on my storage. I'm running the code as an kivy apk on Android so i cant change the permissions of my code.
I already tried:

```
dir = [x[0] for x in os.walk("/storage/")]
```

but everytime i try to list a directory i'm not allowed to read it just stops and doesn't list any more dirs although my apk has android permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

EDIT:
I now used

```
file_dir = [os.path.join(root,file) for root, dir, files in os.walk("/storage/") for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.mp4')]
```

to skip all folders i can't access but appereantly i've got broken folders in my storage. Is there a way to skip the folders i can't read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code skips those files you cant access due perms

```
 abs_file_paths=[os.path.join(root, file) for root, dir, files in os.walk(dir_to_extract) for file in files]
```

Comment: I tried, but appereantly there are some broken folders and your code does not skip them. Is there a way to try to read the folder and pass when it can't?

Comment: for folder in folders: 
try: read_folder(folder) 
except: logger.error(f'cant read folder {folder}, {traceback.format_exc()}')

Answer (score 0):

You may use listdir:

```
mydir = [i for i in os.listdir('/storage/')]
```